# Using multiple functions depending on variable with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to make my code more concise but the current implementation I have is much less efficient than the more verbose method.

Why is the verbose method so much faster than the concise method and is there a way to make it more concise without sacrificing speed?

```r
library(data.table)
mtcars_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

min_vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")
max_vars <- c("hp", "gear")

# Preferred but slow  method
system.time(mtcars_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, .SD, .SDcols = ..min_vars], min, na.rm = TRUE),
                          lapply(.SD[, .SD, .SDcols = ..max_vars], max, na.rm = TRUE)),
                      by = wt])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.05    0.02    0.04

# Not concise but fast method
system.time(mtcars_dt[, .(mpg = min(mpg, na.rm = TRUE),
                          cyl = min(cyl, na.rm = TRUE),
                          hp = max(hp, na.rm = TRUE),
                          gear = max(gear, na.rm = TRUE)),
                      by = wt])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

# Check if results from two methods are equal
x <- mtcars_dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, .SD, .SDcols = ..min_vars], min, na.rm = TRUE),
              lapply(.SD[, .SD, .SDcols = ..max_vars], max, na.rm = TRUE)),
          by = wt]

y <- mtcars_dt[, .(mpg = min(mpg, na.rm = TRUE),
              cyl = min(cyl, na.rm = TRUE),
              hp = max(hp, na.rm = TRUE),
              gear = max(gear, na.rm = TRUE)),
          by = wt]

all.equal(x, y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `mtcars_dt[, c(lapply(mget(min_vars), min, na.rm = TRUE),
                  lapply(mget(max_vars), max, na.rm = TRUE)),
              by = wt]` should be comparable in speed to the verbose method. I think the first method is taking longer because you're making 2 extra `[.data.table` calls for each group (and there's a lot of `wt` groups in mtcars)

Comment: `mget()` solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniColitti you might also want to take a look at the `dplyr` package. I do not know exactly what you desired outcome is, but using something like `mtcars_dt %>% group_by(wt) %>% summaris_at(min_vars, ~min(., na.rm=T)` is even nicer to read and usually also fast. Here %>% is the piping operator, indicating which actions should be taken after each other.

Comment: @Annet I'm summarising in the context of a non-equi join and need to take advantage of the memory efficiency afforded by `data.table`.